# Issues with Network security group deployment using python : NetworkSecurityGroup' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-network

Thanks in advance, I'm trying to create NSG using python and getting an issue with

> Message=Unable to build a model: Unable to deserialize to object:
>   type, AttributeError: 'NetworkSecurityGroup' object has no attribute
>   'lower', DeserializationError: Unable to deserialize to object: type,
>   AttributeError: 'NetworkSecurityGroup' object has no attribute 'lower'

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute.models import DiskCreateOption
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import NetworkSecurityGroup
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import SecurityRule
import azure.mgmt.network.models

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 'XXXXX'
GROUP_NAME = 'AQRG'
LOCATION = 'westus'
VM_NAME = 'myVM'



def get_credentials():
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = 'xxxx',
        secret = 'xxxx',
        tenant = 'xxxx'
    )

    return credentials
def create_network_security_group(network_client):
        params_create = azure.mgmt.network.models.NetworkSecurityGroup(
            location=LOCATION,
            security_rules=[
                azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRule(
                    name='rdp rule',
                    access=azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRuleAccess.allow,
                    description='test security rule',
                    destination_address_prefix='*',
                    destination_port_range='3389',
                    direction=azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRuleDirection.inbound,
                    priority=500,
                    protocol=azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRuleProtocol.tcp,
                    source_address_prefix='*',
                    source_port_range='*',
                ),
            ],
        ),
        result_create = network_client.network_security_groups.create_or_update(
            GROUP_NAME,
            'nsg-vm',
            params_create,
        )

        return result_create.result()



# creation_result = create_network_security_group(network_client)
# print("------------------------------------------------------")
# print(creation_result)
# input('Press enter to continue...')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    credentials = get_credentials()

    resource_group_client = ResourceManagementClient(
        credentials, 
        SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )
    network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
        credentials, 
        SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
        credentials, 
        SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )


    creation_result = create_network_security_group(network_client)
    print("------------------------------------------------------")
    print(creation_result)
    input('Press enter to continue...')
```

I'm new to python and created this piece of code after few hours. I'm getting this error while deploying NSG and will have to work on the linking NSG to subnet

```
def attach_network_security_group(network_client):
    params_create = azure.mgmt.network.models.Subnet(
            network_security_group='nsg-vm',
        )

    result_create = network_client.subnets.create_or_update(
            GROUP_NAME,
            VNET,
            SUBNET,
            params_create,
        )

    return result_create.result()
```

Comment: If the code is all of it or a piece of it? I do not see that you authenticate to the Azure?

Comment: Code was just a snippet which is giving exception. I've added rest of the code about login and calling the snippet as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue,  it's just a little mistake. You just need to delete the `,` and then the code will like below:

```
params_create = azure.mgmt.network.models.NetworkSecurityGroup(
            location=LOCATION,
            security_rules=[
                azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRule(
                    name='rdp rule',
                    access=azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRuleAccess.allow,
                    description='test security rule',
                    destination_address_prefix='*',
                    destination_port_range='3389',
                    direction=azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRuleDirection.inbound,
                    priority=500,
                    protocol=azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRuleProtocol.tcp,
                    source_address_prefix='*',
                    source_port_range='*',
                ),
            ],
        )
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. Can you tell me how can i link NSG to a subnet?
I'm trying to find it in below git repo but unable to find it.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt-network/tests/test_mgmt_network.py

Comment: @aquib.qureshi You take a look at the [create_or_update method of subnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2018_12_01.operations.subnets_operations.subnetsoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--virtual-network-name--subnet-name--subnet-parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false--polling-true----operation-config-), and set the network security group in the `subnet_parameters`.

Comment: Hi Charles, I've used the same function but not sure if I'm making mistake in formatting.

Can you please check the question I've updated with the attach code as well.

Comment: @aquib.qureshi I don't think you can just use the NSG name. It needs the `NetworkSecurityGroup`. You can try to use the `creation_result` of the NSG.

Comment: Thanks Charles, still there is something wrong in the code. We're missing address prefix in the azure.mgmt.network.models.Subnet. Let me create another question for this as the main question is already answered

Comment: Hi Charles, If you get time please have a look

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980556/attaching-nsg-to-subnet-using-python

Comment: @aquib.qureshi Well, I'm looking.