# Attaching NSG to Subnet using python

Tags: python, azure, subnet

I'm trying to create NSG and then attach it to a existing subnet.
I've successfully able to create the NSG but it throws an error while attaching it to subnet. Stating that the address prefix cannot be null. Do we have to pass the address prefix as well? in below function?

```
params_create = azure.mgmt.network.models.Subnet(
```

Below is the full code snippet.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute.models import DiskCreateOption
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import NetworkSecurityGroup
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import SecurityRule
import azure.mgmt.network.models

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 'xxx'
GROUP_NAME = 'xxxx'
LOCATION = 'xxxx'
VM_NAME = 'myVM'
VNET = 'existingvnet'
SUBNET = 'default'

def get_credentials():
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = 'xxx',
        secret = 'xxxx',
        tenant = 'xxxx'
    )

    return credentials

def create_network_security_group(network_client):
    params_create = azure.mgmt.network.models.NetworkSecurityGroup(
            location=LOCATION,
            security_rules=[
                azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRule(
                    name='rdprule',
                    access=azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRuleAccess.allow,
                    description='test security rule',
                    destination_address_prefix='*',
                    destination_port_range='3389',
                    direction=azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRuleDirection.inbound,
                    priority=500,
                    protocol=azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRuleProtocol.tcp,
                    source_address_prefix='*',
                    source_port_range='*',
                ),
            ],
        )

    result_create_NSG = network_client.network_security_groups.create_or_update(
            GROUP_NAME,
            'nsg-vm',
            params_create,
        )

    return result_create_NSG.result()

def attach_network_security_group(network_client,creation_result_nsg):
    params_create = azure.mgmt.network.models.Subnet(
            network_security_group= creation_result_nsg,
        )

    result_create = network_client.subnets.create_or_update(
            GROUP_NAME,
            VNET,
            SUBNET,
            params_create,
        )

    return result_create.result()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    credentials = get_credentials()

resource_group_client = ResourceManagementClient(
    credentials, 
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID
)
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    credentials, 
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID
)
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    credentials, 
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID
)


creation_result_nsg = create_network_security_group(network_client)
print("------------------------------------------------------")
print(creation_result_nsg)
input('Press enter to continue...')

creation_result = attach_network_security_group(network_client,creation_result_nsg)
print("------------------------------------------------------")
print(creation_result)
input('Press enter to continue...')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that means you are not passing it the address prefix it should use. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models.subnet%28class%29?view=azure-python) you need to pass in `address_prefix` parameter. so add it to your params_create, something like this:

```
params_create = Subnet(
    address_prefix = "10.0.0.0/24",
    network_security_group = azure.mgmt.network.models.NetworkSecurityGroup(xxx)
)
```

Comment: I checked that and was unable to find out which parameter is mandatory. How do you determine parameters which are mandatory?

Thanks for help Gleb as always.

Comment: well, there is no way to know that, i dont think its documented somewhere. but since its explicitly asking address_prefix - it is mandatory. also, if you look at [api reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/subnets/createorupdate) it is also presenting an example with only address_prefix defined. so it should be mandatory. and the only one mandatory. for other resources the logic is the same. it comes from experience\api reference\examples

Comment: Sure Gleb, I only referred python documentation. I should also check for REST api documentation to get more info. thanks once again